# Android dialog and maintaining of its state on screen orientation change

Tags: android, dialog, state, onrestoreinstancestate

I`m having trouble with maintaining the dialog on orientation change.
I`m using onSaveInstanceState, onRestoreInstanceState.
But i have a null in onRestore. I want the dialog to show the same values when i change orientation of the screen.
Thanx!
Here is the dialog:

```
private void ratedialog() {

        dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Rate it!");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();

        seekbar = (SeekBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.rate_seekbar);
        button_done = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_done);
        seekbar_result = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.seekbar_result);
        checkBox_seen = (CheckBox) dialog.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_seen);

        button_done.setOnClickListener(EditActivity.this);
        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(EditActivity.this);
        checkBox_seen.setOnCheckedChangeListener(EditActivity.this);

        Intent callingIntent = getIntent();
        if (callingIntent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)) {

            Movie movie = dbHandler.query(id);
            rate = movie.getRate();
            seen = movie.isSeen();

            seekbar.setProgress(rate);
            image_seen.setImageResource(R.drawable.seen);
            image_seen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            checkBox_seen.setChecked(seen);
        }else if (callingIntent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_EDIT)){
            seekbar.setProgress(rate);
            image_seen.setImageResource(R.drawable.seen);
            image_seen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            checkBox_seen.setChecked(seen);
        }else if (callingIntent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)){
            seekbar.setProgress(rate);
            image_seen.setImageResource(R.drawable.seen);
            image_seen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            checkBox_seen.setChecked(seen);
        }


    }
```

onSave:

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);


        if (rate != 0){
            outState.putInt("rate", rate);
        }
        outState.putBoolean("check_box", seen);
```

onRestrore:

```
@Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        seen = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("check_box");
        rate = savedInstanceState.getInt("rate");
       checkBox_seen.setChecked(seen);
       seekbar.setProgress(rate);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling recreation of Activity adding `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to your activity in manifest file.

Comment: You mean disable the orientation change?

Comment: No. Every time when orientation changes activity recreates so data in that activity flushes. This will prevent activity recreation on orientation change.

Comment: i posted it in the question

Comment: I don`t think it has something to do with the manifest, the question is how to make the dialog open again onRestore with the same values...

Comment: I think you did not read my answer carefully. In manifest file you can define activity's properties that can help you solve your problem.